# How can I add a role to someone if i don't want use discord.ext.commands? (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a bot without discord.ext.commands and I need to know, how can I give role to someone, on the server.

Like this:

```py
user = message.author
role = "something role name like Admin"
await client.addrole(user, role)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use [discord.Member.edit](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.edit) or [discord.Member.add_roles](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.add_roles). As far as I know ext.commands has nothing to do with editing members and such. It's just for making commands.

```py
server = client.get_guild(server_ID) # Replace with the server ID
role_to_append = server.get_role(role_ID) # Replace with the role ID
user = server.get_member(member_ID) # Replace with the member ID you want to edit roles from

# user.roles is the user's current roles, you just edit it with what you want the new roles to be.
await user.edit(roles=user.roles + [role_to_append])

# or to just append a role(s)
await user.add_roles(role_to_append)
```

Comment: You can also use `user.add_roles` and `user.remove_roles`

Comment: Ah yes forgot about that one, thanks @SecretAgent . I'll edit it in